# Ruby on Rails on Mac not generating model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I type into the terminal `rails generate model Message`, this comes up in the terminal and there is no model called Messages. What should I do? I am using El Capitan.  [This is the Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVGvP.png)

Comment: maybe you have to cd into the right folder before generating the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a model by

```
rails generate model Article title:string text:text
```

as copied from this [page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) You can also generate a controller by

```
rails g controller controllername new create
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer as you just added columns to the model, but in his case he can't even generate a model.

Comment: His picture in the question displays no error. Just instructions from rails.

Comment: You get those instructions if your generate doesn't work (e.g. you mistyped your command).. but if 'rails generate model Message' doesn't work then 'rails generate model Article title:string text:text ' doesn't work either.

Comment: I've replicated this on my Mac and I got exactly same behavior, you can't visit Hollywood in NY, you actually have to be in California to see Hollywood. Same as you can't generate a rails controller or model if you are not inside a rails project.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have probably created a new rails project but you have not navigated into the folder of that project yet. 
So 
    cd into-the-name-of-project
and then you can successfully generate models and controller there.

And if you have not created the project yet, run this command - rails new name-of-project